# Проблема в go с $GOROOT и $GOPATH

Tags: golang

Добрый день.

Проблема в go с $GOROOT и $GOPATH.

Сначала программа не запускается, ругается. Проверяю параметр $GOROOT и $GOPATH   -go env, задаю `$GOPATH export GOPATH='c:\Go'`, потом проверяю - go env. Всё задалось.

Пишу программу, где подключается пакет:

```
import (
    "code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket"
)
```

Получается вот такой ответ http://prntscr.com/6j7qm7

Работаю на Винде.

Компилирую. Получаю ошибку. 
Что мне с этим делать? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Значение переменной GOPATH не должно быть равно значению GOROOT.
На Windows значением GOROOT является путь к GO "C:\go\" или "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\go\", если го был установлен из mysys.
 Попробуйте установить следующее значение для  GOPATH - "C:\gopath\".
Из документации:

> The GOPATH environment variable specifies the location of your workspace. It is likely the only environment variable you'll need to set when developing Go code.
>   To get started, create a workspace directory and set GOPATH accordingly. Your workspace can be located wherever you like, but we'll use $HOME/go in this document. Note that this must not be the same path as your Go installation.

http://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH

Answer (score 0):

Так надо инсталлировать сперва внешние пакеты.
Для этого выполните команду

`go get code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket`

А еще говорят, что ни в коем случае нельзя устанавливать переменную `GOPATH` на `GOROOT`. Перенесите свой проект в другую директорию.

Comment: Выругался при подключении http://prntscr.com/6j95e8   -Это типа нет по такой запускаемого файла по этой ссылке?
А если другую подключает- github.com/gorilla/websocket не ругается.

Comment: Судя по ошибке, Ваша конфигурация не умеет работать с Merjurial Hg.